# Check if a pointer points to a valid structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have N statically allocated structures.

```
struct exemple{
     ...
}

struct exemple array[N];
struct exemple *test_ptr = 0x3; /* random address */
```

Can I check if test_prt points to a valid address? i.e. it points to one "struct example" allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only check if pointer is valid by doing `pointer != NULL` because anything except `NULL' is treated by *valid pointer*.

In your case, to check if your pointer points to any of your array entry, you can only do this:

```
size_t i = 0;
int isValid = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (test_ptr == &array[i]) {
        isValid = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if (isValid) {
    //Pointer points to one of your array entry
}
```

But in general, you cannot just test if pointer points to specific valid location for you. It is up to you to take care of where it points. It can also have *NON-NULL* value but points to invalid location, for example:

```
int* ptr = malloc(10); //Now points to allocated memory
*ptr = 10;
free(ptr);  //Free memory
*ptr = 10;  //Undefined behaviour, it still points to the same address but
            //we don't know what will happen. Depends on implementation
```

Comment: I knew I could do array check, but I was wondering if there was any more immediate way. thanks

Comment: @alessiovolpe Unfortunatelly, there is no, that's why C is Control language :)

Comment: This is very inefficient for a large array. There **is** a more immediate way, @alessiovolpe.

Comment: @alain it is very inefficient, but there is no other way at all to test if pointer points to valid location rather than check if it is *NON-NULL*. Even if pointer is *NON-NULL*, reading from it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @tilz0R in general, yes, but for an array, see my answer ;-)

Comment: Don't you think `test_ptr >= array && test_ptr <= &array[N-1] && (test_ptr-array) % sizeof(*array) == 0` will be more efficient?

Comment: @tilz0R *since I made corrections to answer you are posting now* . . .uhm, what?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya the trick, you posted in comment was posted by another user and I made corrections. So yeah, I'm aware of that. But anyway, answer to OPs question is NO, there is no way to detect valid pointer in C. Period. End of story.

Comment: You *say* you made corrections, but I don't really see it? Hence the confusion.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Sorry if you are confused. I made correction to answer from alain. Like I said, answer is **no**.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You have to **know**. It's not a problem if you manage your pointers correctly. A good habit is to always set pointers to `0` / `NULL` as soon as you destroy the object they point to. Then you can just test with `if (ptr)` or `if (!ptr)` (or, more verbose: `if (ptr == NULL)` / `if (ptr != NULL)`).

Note that your last assignment

```
struct exemple *test_ptr = 0x3; /* random address */
```

is **invalid**. you can't assign an integer to a pointer. but you can *cast* it to the pointer type;

```
struct exemple *test_ptr = (struct exemple *)0x3; /* random address */
```

The result will depend on your implementation / system.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, you can't test if a pointer is valid or not.

But, if you want to know if a pointer points to an element of an array, you can:

```
if(test_ptr >= &array[0] && test_ptr < &array[N]
        && ((intptr_t)test_ptr - (intptr_t)array)%((intptr_t)(&array[1]) - (intptr_t)array) == 0) {
    // test_ptr points to an element of array
}
```

This works because arrays are allocated contiguously.

Comment: This doesn't work ok in any case. If you want your approach, you have to subtract first: `((intptr_t)test_ptr - (intptr_t)&array[0]) % sizeof...` And better would be to use `test_ptr <= &array[N-1]`. So, your approach is currently *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing subtraction, @tilz0R. But using `array[N - 1]` is not needed, because one may point to one-past-the-end of the array without causing UB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language method but in some circumstances you can try to have some known values at the certain points of the structure. If the pointed memory location has those values you can assume it as valid - but of course you do not have any guarantee. But you need to write your own functions when you create the structure, and when you destroy it (by filling with zeros before freeing the memory). It is a very week workaround - but if you connect with another measures and accept the overhead it makes the probability of the incorrect program behaviour lower.

Sometimes it is called a security cookie.

it is possible of course to make it more complicated - at certain positions you have only offsets to those cookies. It makes less probable that the random position in the memory will have such a chain of data :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question properly.

If you want to know if a pointer points to a struct of some type (cast my structs to `void *` and vice-versa, for example), I do the next way:

```
#include <assert.h>
struct my_struct {
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define MY_STRUCT_MAGIC 0x1234abcd
  uint64_t magic;
#endif
  int my_data;
};

void init_struct(struct my_struct *s, int t_data) {
#ifdef MY_STRUCT_MAGIC
  s->magic = MY_STRUCT_MAGIC;
#endif
  s->my_data = t_data;
}

my_struct *my_struct_cast(void *vs) {
  my_struct *s = vs;
#ifdef MY_STRUCT_MAGIC
  assert(MY_STRUCT_MAGIC == s->magic);
#endif
  return s;
}
```

It has a little bit more code because of inclusion of const-casting, but I think you get the idea.

---

If you want to know if test_ptr points to a aray member, you have to check this way: `test_ptr >= array && test_ptr < &array[sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])])`. If the pointer comes from void, char, or some kind of dangerout ariyhmetic, you could also check for `test_ptr % sizeof(array[0])`

If you want to know if a pointer points to valid memory "ever allocated" by your program, you will have to intercept allocs functions, save returned chunks pointer & size, and compute like the previous example.